# Android change watchface from phone app?

Tags: android, google-api, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am developing some Android wear watchfaces. I have 6 watchfaces classes that use `CanvasWatchFaceService` to generate them. Each is declared as a service in AndroidManifest.xml.

I have created a companion app for them for my phone. I am able to make connections and change the background colors/dials of the watchfaces from my phone directly (if that watchface is active).

However, I cannot seem to find a way to switch between those watchfaces directly from the phone app. Suppose `Watchface1` is active on the watch right now, can I switch to `Watchface2` directly from the phone? I do not want this to simply change the images on the canvas to simulate the `Watchface2`.

I'd like to be able to set them like you can set different watchfaces from the android wear. (By long press and selecting one)

How can I get a list of all currently installed watchfaces on the wear device? How can I then activate one from that list? Is this possible?
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only change the watch face on your Android Wear device via your phone in the official Android Wear app. To achieve what you want to do, you would have to create a single `CanvasWatchFaceService` and switch the watch faces via settings in your companion watch face settings app.

Comment: hmm.. I assumed since the android wear app can do it, third party apps must also be able to.. oh well. THanks.